# Is there a way to keep the 3rd div fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to make the 3rd `div` positioned to `fixed`, because when I clicked the `slideUp` button, the `divs` are collapsing. I want all of them to slide up and down in their current position. I think its due to `flexbox` as it is centering the whole thing. I tried removing that but still it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideUp();
    $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#div3").slideUp(3000);
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideDown();
    $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#div3").slideDown(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
}

#btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
}

button {
  padding: 15px 60px;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 99vw;
}

#flex > div {
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

button:active,
button:visited {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demonstrate slideUP() and slideDown() with different parameters.</h1>
    <button id="btn1">CLick to slideDown boxes</button>
    <button id="btn2">CLick to slideUp boxes</button>
    <div id="flex">
      <div id="div1"></div>
      <div id="div2"></div>
      <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try changing ```justify-content: space-around;``` to ```justify-content: flex-end;```  for id ```#flex```?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan @vitechster i created demo https://jsfiddle.net/eqkds62c/  `justify-content: flex-end;` added css on class when transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this once
You just need to add wrapper `div` and set it's `width`

```
.wrapper{
width:33.33%;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideUp();
    $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#div3").slideUp(3000);
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideDown();
    $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#div3").slideDown(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
}

#btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
}

button {
  padding: 15px 60px;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top:200px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 99vw;
}

#flex > div > div {
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

button:active,
button:visited {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
.wrapper{
width:33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demonstrate slideUP() and slideDown() with different parameters.</h1>
    <button id="btn1">CLick to slideDown boxes</button>
    <button id="btn2">CLick to slideUp boxes</button>
    <div id="flex">
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @shweta Kindly add an explanation too. That would let the author of this question have a better understanding.

Comment: @shwetaramani I think `width:33.33%` or `width:calc(100%/3)`  for better width.

Comment: @shwetaramani Don't need to wrap extra div you can achieve with help of `justify-content: flex-end;` property on `#flex` and in child add `#flex > div { flex: 1 0 33.33%; max-width: 33.33%;}` then existing layout will work without shifting div element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to `wrap` div with `extra` div so You can achieve with existing div structure with help of `justify-content: flex-end;` property on `#flex` div.
And add css on child like: `#flex > div { flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3); max-width: calc(100% / 3);}`.

Flexbox Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can try below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideUp();
    $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#div3").slideUp(3000);
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideDown();
    $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#div3").slideDown(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#flex {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}
#flex > div {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3);
  max-width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: salmon;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Demonstrate slideUP() and slideDown() with different parameters.</h1>
<button id="btn1">CLick to slideDown boxes</button>
<button id="btn2">CLick to slideUp boxes</button>
<div id="flex">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Raeesh interesting approach. Can you add more explanation on how flex and max-width helps us achieve this ?

Comment: Btw this will not work if the first div is made to slide up the last.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Hi Thakur, If you want to change **div direction** like 1st to last and last to 1st then you need to play with `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` property... It's behave like `float: left;` or `float: right;` in flexbox layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, this will automatically adjust based on how many `divs` you are putting inside your `#flex`. You are correct about the problem in your divs are, once they got 0 height, they will tend to disappear, and since they are centered by flex, divs are tend to center itself. Now enclosing it in divs will prevent it from disappearing.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideUp();
    $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#div3").slideUp(3000);
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideDown();
    $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#div3").slideDown(3000);
  });
$("#flex div div").parent().css({
    "width":((100 / ($("#flex div div").parent().length)).toFixed(0)-1)+ "%",
    "display":"inline-block",
    "vertical-align":"top"
});
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
}

#btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
}

button {
  padding: 15px 60px;
}

#flex {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 99vw;
}

#flex > div > div{
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30vh;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

button:active,
button:visited {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demonstrate slideUP() and slideDown() with different parameters.</h1>
<button id="btn1">CLick to slideDown boxes</button>
<button id="btn2">CLick to slideUp boxes</button>
<div id="flex">
    <div>
        <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach. This doesn't rely on `display:flex` at all. Here we make the `flex` div have a `position:relative` and it's child i.e. `flex>div` or `box` have a `position:absolute`.

Now on starting of the JS code, I have added a bit to dynamically take care of the `left` position of these **absolutely positioned** child elements. In our case , `div1` will end up with `left = 0%`, `div2` with `left = 33%` and `div3` with `left = 66%` . I have added a smooth `transition` as well to make up for the delay in positioning the elements.

Now your `slideUp` and `slideDown` is working on **absolutely positioned** elements which actually don't occupy any space like normal **position:static** (yes this is by default) elements. So you don't need to wrap them in additional individual divs now.

Also this is just one of the many approaches. Felt fancy so sharing it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let leftPos = 0;
  let boxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.box')];
  for(let index = 1;index<boxes.length;index++)
  {
      boxes[index].style.left = `${(100/boxes.length)*index}%`;
  }
   
  $("#btn2").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideUp();
    $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
    $("#div3").slideUp(3000);
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#div1").slideDown();
    $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
    $("#div3").slideDown(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#btn1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60vw;
}

#btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20vw;
}

button {
  padding: 15px 60px;
}

#flex {

  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  width: 99vw;
}

#flex > div {
  width: 30vw;
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 30vh;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: salmon;
  left:0
}

#div3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
    left:0
}

button:active,
button:visited {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demonstrate slideUP() and slideDown() with different parameters.</h1>
    <button id="btn1">CLick to slideDown boxes</button>
    <button id="btn2">CLick to slideUp boxes</button>
    <div id="flex">
      <div class='box' id="div1"></div>
      <div class='box' id="div2"></div>
      <div  class='box' id="div3"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```